# command line VIM does not change background (stays black)?

Tags: vim, command-prompt, color-scheme

I have tried this in both gVIM and VIM
the background is correctly applied in gVIM but not in VIM, it just stays black.
I use the command, `:color zenburn`
I am running this in Windows XP, Command Prompt
I also wonder how many colours command prompt in xp supports.

Comment: You might want to check the [VIM Wiki article on using GUI color schemes in a terminal](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_GUI_color_settings_in_a_terminal).  However, I've voted to close this question, since it's not programming-related.  SuperUser is probably a better home for it.

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler - It has been decided that Vim questions are ontopic on SO http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su

Comment: @Idigas: You'll have to forgive me for not siding with the popular opinion of that Meta question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colour sets between "gui" vim (`gvim`) and "console" vim (`vim`) are completely different. They can even be completely different for the same colour scheme.

I'm unfamiliar with the "zenburn" scheme, but it sounds like it makes different choices depending on whether you're using the GUI or not.

The [`:highlight`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#%3ahighlight) command has different arguments (`term=`, `cterm=`, `gui=`, etc) that define the different colours used by vim in different modes. You should be able to look at your `zenburn.vim` colour definition file to see what it is using.

Answer (score 1):

The colors for the GUI version and the console version of Vim are set differently in each colorscheme file. They don't even have to be set at all (some colorschemes define only the values for the GUI version and vice versa).

That being said, open up your colorscheme file (zenburn.vim) and look it up. If you're interested in the background color, check it up for a line looking similar to

```
hi Normal guibg=... guifg=.... ctermbg=.... ctermfg=...
```

or something similar.

The values should be there - change them to your liking if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

In a windows command prompt, I find only 16 color color schemes work well.  You may prefer to install cygwin and include mintty in the installation.  mintty is a better terminal and I have no problem with 256 colors.  http://code.google.com/p/mintty/